# How to detect scroll behaviour in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to detect three scenarios :

1.- User scroll vertically (down) and notify to hide a button

2.- User stop scrolls and notify to hide button

3.- User scroll vertically (up) and notify to show the button

4.- User is in the bottom of the list and there are no more items and notify to show the button.

What I've tried is :

First approach is to use `nestedScrollConnection` as follows

```
val isVisible = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
                .apply { targetState = true }
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
                object : NestedScrollConnection {
                    override fun onPreScroll(
                        available: Offset,
                        source: NestedScrollSource
                    ): Offset {
                        return Offset.Zero
                    }

                    override fun onPostScroll(
                        consumed: Offset,
                        available: Offset,
                        source: NestedScrollSource
                    ): Offset {
                        isVisible.targetState = false
                        return super.onPostScroll(consumed, available, source)
                    }
                }
            }
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                    .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            )
```

What I've tried is when y > 0 is going up, else is going down, but the others I don't know how to get them.

Another approach I followed is :

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                state = scrollState,
```

But I don't know how to get if it's last item or not, I can get if the scroll is in progress.

### Note

Answer from Skizo works but with this it's a bit weird because if you scroll up slowly the Y sometimes is not what I want and then hide it again, is there any way to leave some scroll to start reacting to this? For instance, scroll X pixels to start showing / hiding.

What I want is to hide/show is a Float Action Button depending on the scroll (the scenarios are the ones from above)

I've found this way, but it is using the offset and I'd like to animate the `FloatActionButton` instead of appearing from the bottom like a fade in/fade out I was using the [Animation Visibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/package-summary#AnimatedVisibility(kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition,androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition,kotlin.Function1)) and I got this working with fade in/fade out but now, how can I adapt the code from github to use `Animation Visibility`? And also add this when the user ends scrolling that from now in the code is just while scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you'd go about achieving these,

1.) Detect The Scrolling Direction (Vertically Up, or Vertically Down)

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
            } else {
                previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }.also {
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

Now, just create a listState variable and use it with this Composable to retrieve the scrolling dierection.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val scrollingUp = listState.isScrollingUp()
```

Then, as you say, you'd like to get notified if the user stops scrolling, so for that you can just create a variable known as `restingScrollPosition`, I'll name it `rsp` for short. Now that you are familiar with the required helper methods, all that is required is devising a mechanism to trigger an event based on the value of the current scroll position that triggers the code in concern if the value has been the same for a particular amount of time (the definition of the scroll being "at rest").

So, here it is

```
var rsp by remember { mutableStateOf(listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) } 
var isScrolling by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } // to keep track of the scroll-state

LaunchedEffect(key = listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset){ //Recomposes every time the key changes

/*This block will also be executed
 on the start of the program,
 so you might want to handle
 that with the help of another variable.*/
 
 isScrolling = true // If control reaches here, we're scrolling
 launch{
  isScrolling = false
  delay(100) //If there's no scroll after a hundred seconds, update rsp
  if(!isScrolling){
     rsp = listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
     /* Execute your trigger here,
        this denotes the scrolling has stopped */
    }
 }
}
```

I don't think I would be explaining the workings of the last code here, please analyze it yourself to gain a better understanding, it's not difficult.

Ah yes to achieve the last objective, you can just use a little swashbuckling with the APIs, specifically methods like `lazyListState.layoutInfo`. It has all the info you'll require about the items currently visible on-screen, and so you can also use it to implement your subtle need where you wish to allow for a certain amount to be scrolled before triggering the codeblock. Just have a look at the availannle info in the object and you should be able to start it up.

**UPDATE:**

Based on the info provided in the comments added below as of yesterday, this should be the implementation,

You have a FAB somewhere in your heirarchy, and you wish to animate it's visibility based on the `isScrollingUp`, which is bound to the Lazy Scroller defined somewhere else in the heirarchy,

In that case, you can take a look at [state-hoisting](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#8), which is a general best practice for declarative programming.

Just hoist the `isScrollingUp()` output up to the point where your FAB is declared, or please share the complete code if you need specific instructions based on your use-case. I would require the entire heirarchy to be able to help you out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem some days ago and I did a mix of what you say.

To show or hide then scrolling up or down with the `Y` is enough.

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
   object : NestedScrollConnection {
             override fun onPreScroll(
             available: Offset,
             source: NestedScrollSource
         ): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            isVisible.targetState = delta > 0
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

And to detect there's no more items you can use

```
fun isLastItemVisible(lazyListState: LazyListState): Boolean {
 val lastItem = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
 return lastItem == null || lastItem.size + lastItem.offset <= layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset
}
```

Comment: But with this it's a bit weird because if you scroll up slowly the Y sometimes is not what I want and then hide it again, is there any way to leave some scroll to start reacting to this? For instance, scroll X pixels to start showing / hiding

Answer (score 0):

For 1 and 3, if you want to specify a specific scroll distance before showing/hiding something, you can create a `NestedScrollConnection` with its own state.

Here is an example of an implementation that may give you some ideas. `CustomScrollConnection.isScrollingDown` would return `true` when `downThreshold` is reached, and it would change to `false` when `upThreshold` is reached.

```
private class CustomScrollConnection(
    downThreshold: Dp = 0.dp,
    upThreshold: Dp = 0.dp,
    density: Density
) : NestedScrollConnection {

    var isScrollingDown by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    private val downThresholdPx = with(density) { -downThreshold.toPx() }
    private val upThresholdPx = with(density) { upThreshold.toPx() }
    private var isScrollingDownDelta = 0f

    override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
        val delta = available.y
        updateState(delta)
        return Offset.Zero
    }

    private fun updateState(delta: Float) {
        val isChangingDirections = isScrollingDownDelta.sign != delta.sign

        isScrollingDownDelta = if (isChangingDirections) {
            delta
        } else {
            isScrollingDownDelta + delta
        }.coerceIn(downThresholdPx, upThresholdPx)

        val isUpScroll = isScrollingDownDelta == upThresholdPx && delta > 0
        val isDownScroll = isScrollingDownDelta == downThresholdPx && delta < 0

        val continueDownScroll = isScrollingDown && !isUpScroll
        isScrollingDown = continueDownScroll || isDownScroll
    }
}
```

And you can create an instance like this before passing it to the `nestedScroll` modifier.

```
val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

val customScrollConnection = remember(localDensity) {
    CustomScrollConnection(
        downThreshold = DOWN_SCROLL_THRESHOLD,
        upThreshold = UP_SCROLL_THRESHOLD,
        density = localDensity
    )
}
```

Additional code would be needed to use it with `rememberSaveable`.

For 2, if you are using `LazyListState`, you can see if `!lazyListState.isScrollInProgress` helps.

For 4, you can try using `!lazyListState.canScrollForward`. Or, in an implementation of `NestedScrollConnection`, if you override `onPostScroll`, you can check if `consumed.y == 0f && available.y < 0f`; this could mean you reached the bottom.